# Need help for what seems to be a very simple SQL Query

Tags: sql-server

I've been working on it for hours and what seems to be a very simple query is driving me (quite) crazy.
I have 2 tables:

Items

```
Code    Var
AAI85CLASS2000              9005N
AAI85CLASS2000              9005P
```

Times

```
Code            Var     Time
AAI85CLASS2000  NULL    8,68
AAI85CLASS2000  CROM    9,68
AAI85CLASS2000  9005N   19,68
```

Result I'd like to get

```
Code                        Var     Time
AAI85CLASS2000              9005N   19,68
AAI85CLASS2000              9005P   8,68
```

When there's a matching Var, the specific Time should be considered. When there's no matching Var, the generic Time (where Var is NULL) should be considered.
I ask for help. Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you do a straightforward `INNER JOIN`? What do you mean by "Time should be considered"? *How* should it be considered?

Comment: When there's no Var matching, the Time where Var equals NULL should be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using `Outer Join`

```
SELECT a.Code,
       a.Var,
       COALESCE(b.time, c.time)
FROM   Items a
       LEFT JOIN Times b
              ON a.Code = b.Code
                 AND a.Var = b.Var
       LEFT JOIN Times c
              ON ( a.Code = b.Code
                   AND a.Var = c.Var
                   AND b.Var IS NULL ) -- To find the non matching var's in previous join
                  OR c.Var IS NULL  -- To find the time from var which is NULL
```

- [**Live Demo**](http://rextester.com/VWY87507)

Comment: Thank you, the result I get is a NULL Time on the Record where Var equals 9005P. The result I'm searching for should return a Time equal to 8,68.

Comment: @user3293444 - Did you check the demo that is not the case

Comment: I've tested the code and it returns a NULL Time value where Var is 9005P. What do you mean with "that is not the case"?

Comment: @user3293444 - Did you check the demo link present in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select i.code, i.var, case when max(t.var) is not null then max(case when t.var is not null then t.time end) else max(t.time) end time
From items i left join times t
On i.code = t.code and (i.var = t.var or t.var is null)
Group by i.code, i.var;
```

Comment: Thank you, the result I get is a NULL Time on the Record where Var equals 9005P. The result I'm searching for should return a Time equal to 8,68.

Comment: I've tested this code and it produces the exact same output as you expect.

Comment: When I run the code I get...AAI85CLASS2000 9005N 19,68
AAI85CLASS2000            9005P NULL. 19,68 is OK but NULL is not. I need the NULL to be 8,68. Do you get 8,68?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
SELECT  I.Code, 
        I.Var, 
        ISNULL(T.Time, (SELECT Time FROM Times WHERE Var IS NULL AND Code = I.Code)) Time
FROM Items I
LEFT JOIN Times T ON I.Code = T.Code AND I.Var = T.Var
```

Comment: Thank you, the result I get is a NULL Time on the Record where Var equals 9005P. The result I'm searching for should return a Time equal to 8,68.